# select not working in MUIDataTable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, mui-datatable

i have a react application where i used the mui-datatable npm package to display a datatable but rows refuse to get selected.

the checkboxes never update even when selecting one row.
when clicking on the checkbox, its state doesn't change. I looked everywhere for a solution but no one seems to have had the same problem in the past

Comment: Please show your code.